# Cannot convert value of the same type that use generic type

Tags: swift

```swift
import Foundation

class Event<T: Decodable> { }

protocol ManagerProtocol {
    func handle<T: Decodable>(event: [Event<T>])
}

class Manager<T: Decodable>: ManagerProtocol {
    
    var items: [Event<T>] = []
    
    func handle<T>(event: [Event<T>]) where T : Decodable {
        event.forEach { event in
            getEvent(event)
        }
    }
    
    func getEvent<T: Decodable>(_ event: Event<T>){
        items.append(event)
        print(event)
    }
}
```

I using this code in playground to test generics but in this case on line:

```
items.append(event)
```

Gives me the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Playground.Event' to expected argument type 'Playground.Event'

I also remove `<T: Decodable>` from `getEvent` function but in this scenario I'll get error on:

```swift
func handle<T>(event: [Event<T>]) where T : Decodable {
    event.forEach { event in
        getEvent(event)
    }
}
```

`getEvent(event)` also gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
func handle<T>(event: [Event<T>]) where T : Decodable {
```

This says that `handle` can be passed **any** Event, no matter its `T`, and it will append it to an Array of Event for some specific `T` that may be different. Given how you've written this, I could write:

```
let manager = Manager<String>()
manager.handle(event: [Event<Int>()])
```

That's not valid, and your code doesn't actually allow that.

What you mean is:

```
func handle(event: [Event<T>]) {
```

and similarly:

```
func getEvent(_ event: Event<T>){
```

This mean that it requires `T` to be the same `T` as Manager's. All together, the code looks like this:

```
class Manager<T: Decodable> {

    var items: [Event<T>] = []

    func handle(event: [Event<T>]) {
        event.forEach { event in
            getEvent(event)
        }
    }

    func getEvent(_ event: Event<T>){
        items.append(event)
        print(event)
    }
}
```

This gets rid of the ManagerProtocol, which isn't doing anything. I strongly recommend removing it if you can. But if you believe you want it, it would look like:

```
protocol ManagerProtocol {
    associatedtype T: Decodable
    func handle(event: [Event<T>])
}
```

Note that this is a "protocol with an associatedtype" and so has many restrictions on how it can be used.